# how to parse un Array of object with Circe

Tags: scala, circe

I have a json

`{
  "field" : [
    {
      "value" : 1.0
    },
    {
      "value" : 2.0
    }
  ]
}`

How do I get a `List[String]` that are of values List(1.0, 2.0) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would do it like:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser.decode

case class ValueWrapper(value: Double)
case class Result(field: Seq[ValueWrapper])

decode[Result](jsonString).map(_.field.map(_.toString)).getOrElse(Seq.empty)
```

Actually, you could do that without `Decoder` derivation. Basically it means that you do not use most often used part of Circe, and instead rely on [Circe optics](https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/docs/src/main/tut/optics.md). I guess it would be sth like (I haven't tested it!):

```
import io.circe.optics.JsonPath._
root.field.value.double.getAll(jsonString).map(_.toString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Circe optics is the most concise way to do that.

```
import io.circe.optics.JsonPath._
import io.circe.parser._

val json = parse(jsonStr).right.get // TODO: handle parse errors

root.field.each.value.double.getAll(json) // == List(1.0, 2.0)
```